# Prevent program from being started on RDP logon

Tags: windows, rdp, startup, autorun

I got a small problem. I have a program which has to run all the time on the server (Windows 2008). It's not a service but a normal application. It is located in startup. The problem is its working with a database and isn't allowed to run two times. When someone logs in via RDP it gets started a second time. Is there a way to prevent it within Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want an application to be launched at user login, then take it out of the Startup folder.

Answer (score 0):

Run the application from a batch script

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq myapp.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "myapp.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" <call executable>
```